# Problem with Cart Creation in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side. Attached Screenshots for reference. i am new to Sitecore Commerce,Trying to create a cart and adding items to the cart. but getting the below error. what could be the issue, did i miss some reference to commerce.

Commerce AUthoringLog:

```
39 21:11:22 ERROR ClientCertificateValidationMiddleware: Message = The
given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
present in the dictionary.    at
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()    at
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
context)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
context)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Commerce.Core.ClientCertificateValidationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()

19532 13:48:57 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Nested Exception

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: result.Cart
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.MarketingAutomation
   at Sitecore.Commerce.MarketingAutomation.Pipelines.Carts.Common.UpdateVisitorInAutomationPlan.Process(ServicePipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Services.ServiceProvider.RunPipeline[TRequest,TResult](String pipelineName, TRequest request)
```

[image]

Exception is triggering from `Proxy.DoCommand(container.SetCartCustomerData(myrequest.Cart.Id, userData));`

Proxy is `Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SCXA or it is a custom implementation? Since you are getting `401 unauthorized`, check for the certificate thumbprint stored in the authoring config and your engine connect config must have the same thumbprint. `c:\inetpub\wwwroot<storefront>\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config`. If this doesn't solve the problem, please provide the error in the log files for both `Website` and the `Authoring role`.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, i have checked certificate thumbprint is same in all the commerce roles and Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config. regarding the logs, for some reason logs are not coming in CommerceAuthoring_sc9 website. i have shared the log from the sitecore with my original post. Please let me know what else i need to check from my end.

Comment: Added Logs from commerce authoring to my original post..